# Dynamic addition of textbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is quite frustrating. My code was working fine until last week. I am adding multiple textboxes to my **HTML** page when the user changes [using `change()`] the value in a dropdown selection.

*Here's the **HTML** code snippet:*

```
<div id="files" class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">No. of files</label>
    <div class="controls" >
        <select id="files" name="files" class="span3">
            <option value="">--Select Option--</option>
            <?php for($i=1;$i<21;$i++){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option> <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group" id="titles">
    <label class="control-label">File Titles</label>
    <div class="controls" id="titleAdd"></div>
</div>
```

*Here's my **Javascript / jQuery**:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#titles").hide();
    });
    var container;
    // Add & Remove textboxes 
    $("#files").change(function(){

        //Remove all textboxes
        $("#titles").show();
        $(container).empty(); 
        $(container).remove();  
        //"DIV" ELEMENT AND DESIGN IT USING JQUERY ".css()" CLASS.
        container = $('<div>', {class: 'controls'});
        var option = $("#files").val();
        for(i=1;i<=option;i++)
        {
            // Add a TextBox
            $(container).append('<input style="display: block;" type=text name="Description[]" class="span3 input-left-top-margins" id="Description' + i +'"' + 'placeholder="File ' + i + ' Title" />');
        }
        $('#titleAdd').after(container);   // ADD THE DIV ELEMENT IN THE RIGHT PLACE.
    });
```

The most irritating part is that this code was working fine a few days ago.

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: `container` would be undefined at start. Also, your append will duplicate the `id="Description'`

Comment: @Deena - No error. Earlier, when I changed the value of `#files` (say 5), 5 textboxes used to get created. Now, the textboxes aren't getting created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ids `#files`.

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1c3b63f4/ - jQuery will always return an empty string in this assignment: `$("#files").val();`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as accepted to show that this question was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Put your `'$("#files").change(function(){'` code inside `'document.ready'`:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#titles").hide();

    var container;
    // Add & Remove textboxes 
    $("#files").change(function(){

        //Remove all textboxes
        $("#titles").show();
        $(container).empty(); 
        $(container).remove();  
        //"DIV" ELEMENT AND DESIGN IT USING JQUERY ".css()" CLASS.
        container = $('<div>', {class: 'controls'});
        var option = $("#files").val();
        for(i=1;i<=option;i++)
        {
            // Add a TextBox
            $(container).append('<input style="display: block;" type=text name="Description[]" class="span3 input-left-top-margins" id="Description' + i +'"' + 'placeholder="File ' + i + ' Title" />');
        }
        $('#titleAdd').after(container);   // ADD THE DIV ELEMENT IN THE RIGHT PLACE.
    });
 });
```

Comment: Change the ID of main div from 'files' to something else.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

Change id name files to filesdata because you already used id "files" for div

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="files" class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">No. of files</label>
    <div class="controls" >
        <select id="filesdata" name="files" class="span3">
            <option value="">--Select Option--</option>            
                <option value="1">1</option> 
                 <option value="3">2</option> 
                  <option value="3">3</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group" id="titles">
    <label class="control-label">File Titles</label>
    <div class="controls" id="titleAdd"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#titles").hide();

    var container="";
    // Add & Remove textboxes 
    $("#filesdata").change(function(){

        //Remove all textboxes
        $("#titles").show();
        $(container).empty(); 
        $(container).remove();  
        //"DIV" ELEMENT AND DESIGN IT USING JQUERY ".css()" CLASS.
        container = $('<div>', {class: 'controls'});
        var option = $("#filesdata").val();

        for(i=1;i<=option;i++)
        {

            // Add a TextBox
            $(container).append('<input style="display: block;" type=text name="Description[]" class="span3 input-left-top-margins" id="Description' + i +'"' + 'placeholder="File ' + i + ' Title" />');
        }
        $('#titleAdd').after(container);   // ADD THE DIV ELEMENT IN THE RIGHT PLACE.
    });
       });
</script>
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/jqksjzL1/

Comment: Yeah, an amateur mistake! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you have given same `id` "files" for  both `div` and `select`

change

```
<select id="files" name="files" class="span3">
```

to

```
<select id="files-select" name="files" class="span3">
```

and try this js,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#titles").hide();
    });
    var container;
    // Add & Remove textboxes 
    $("#files-select").change(function(){

        //Remove all textboxes
        $("#titles").show();
        $(container).empty(); 
        $(container).remove();  
        //"DIV" ELEMENT AND DESIGN IT USING JQUERY ".css()" CLASS.
        container = $('<div>', {class: 'controls'});
        var option = $("#files-select").val();
        for(i=1;i<=option;i++)
        {
            // Add a TextBox
            $(container).append('<input style="display: block;" type=text name="Description[]" class="span3 input-left-top-margins" id="Description' + i +'"' + 'placeholder="File ' + i + ' Title" />');
        }
        $('#titleAdd').after(container);   // ADD THE DIV ELEMENT IN THE RIGHT PLACE.
    });
```